# custom gem with rails 3. No such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created a custom gem called pdf2html. The gem file is pdf2html-0.1.gem

I placed this file in the vendor directory of rails 3 project.

My Gemfile entry for this gems reads as follows

```
gem 'pdf2html', '0.1' , :path => 'vendor'
```

When I run the bundle install command I get the following message regarding this gem

```
* pdf2html at `vendor` will not be cached.
```

I tried doing a bundle show on this gem it tells me that it is installed in the vendor directory.

Now when  I do a rails console and try to do a require 'pdf2html' I get a "No such file to load error"/

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Thanks 
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pushed the gem and associated files  over to github and then installed it from there using the Gemfile/ bundle install. Now its working fine. I could not figure out how to use the local gem file

Answer (score 1):

I thought the proper way to declare gems was to specify the full path, not the base path, as in:

```
gem 'pdf2html', '0.1', :path => 'vendor/pdf2html'
```

The reason it doesn't error out sooner is that the path `vendor/` actually exists so there's no immediate problem. It's only when you try to require `vendor/pdf2html.rb`, which is missing, that there's an issue raised.

Comment: When specify path as vendor/pdf2html I get an error which reads  "The path `/Users/matt/rails_projects/rbuilder/vendor/pdf2html` does not exist."   Then I created a directory vendor/pdf2html and put the gem file int hat directory. In this case bundle install gives the same error as above